# Paypal REST API for multiple accounts

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have a Java application that has just been updated with e-commerce features that use the Paypal REST API (https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/).

I have multiple customers who run this application, each of them can log in to their own admin panel and manage their store and other features.

The Java client for Paypal REST API is working, I have tested it in the Sandbox of my own Paypal account and also in the live environment.

Question: Will each customer have to go into their Paypal account and activate the REST API to generate their key/secret for use in the Java app or is their a way for me to pay multiple PP acounts from the App/key/secret that is already active for my own PP account?

The only thing the Java app is doing with the PP API is creating and executing a payment.

If each customer has to create their own key/secret is there a quick way for them to do this from their PP admin panel? Currently the only way I know is to go into the developer.paypal.com section of the site, which doesn't seem very intuitive for a non techy.

Comment: *Unless corrected/updated by Paypal folk* - [these were the steps](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27966798/304683) I did to do same and somewhat "eases" the effort for non-technical users/clients..Hth...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At this time the PayPal REST API does not support third party payments in that way. The customer would need to use developer.paypal.com as you suggested to get their own PayPal REST credentials.

You can collect money and send it out using your own REST credentials but this would make you the liable receiver for the purchase.

PayPal has solutions outside of the REST API that might work for you here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/marketplace-split-payments/

The Classic API does have a subject option, the subject is the third party. You do need permissions for some of the API calls; however, the permissions API can ease that process.

Comment: Thanks for the info. The REST API is the thing being pushed by Paypal though, right? I mean, it's the preferred method for integration and the one PP will be extending and adding to?

Comment: I would say PayPal would extend it, we have seen several enhancements such as Payouts come out the past few months.  However, I would focus on what fits your needs now and progressively enhance when possible.